# How to get the value of a mock service with Mockito and Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

How can I capture the value of an operation on a mock repository, as apposed to overriding the return value.

Take for example this test

```java
@Mock
AccountRepository accountRepository;

@InjectMocks
AccountService accountService;

@Test
public void remove_staff_updates_roles() {

    Account account = new Account("username", "pass");

    when(accountRepository.findByUsername(any(String.class))).thenReturn(Optional.of(account));

    accountService.updateStaffStatusByUsername("user", false);

    // How can I capture the account that is to be saved here?

    assertFalse(????.getValue().getRoles().contains(Role.ROLE_STAFF));
    }
```

Then in the service

```java
public Account updateStaffStatusByUsername(String username, Boolean toState) {
    Account account;

    if (toState) {
        return addRole(username, Role.ROLE_STAFF);
    }
    return removeRole(username, Role.ROLE_STAFF);
    
}

Account addRole(String username, Role role) {
    Optional<Account> optionalAccount = accountRepository.findByUsername(username);

    if (account.isEmpty()) {
        throw new CustomException("No account exists with the username: " + username, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    Account account = optionalAccount.get();
    account.addRole(role);

    // I want to intercept this and take the value to evaluate
    return accountRepository.save(account);
}
```

I want to verify that the state of the account has changed correctly when the service is to save the updated account.

Comment: What do you mean by "want to verify that the state of the account has changed correctly when the service is to save the updated account"? Do you want to check weather ROLE_STAFF is added to Account or  accountRepository.save(account) is working or not to update that in DB?

Comment: I want to basically test whether the account that it going to be saved to the DB contains/does not contain the expected ROLE_STAFF

Comment: Not 100% sure I understood your problem, but is it [`ArgumentCaptor`](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argumentcaptor) you're looking for?

Comment: @CameronMcBroom Please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

As here you are passing `Account` (Optional) class object `account` in response to mocked service and same object is being updated and saved in database, you need to validate values in that object.

```
 assertFalse(account.getRoles().contains(Role.ROLE_STAFF)); //or vice-verse
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that [ArgumentCaptor](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) is what you need. Try the following:

```java
@Mock
AccountRepository accountRepository;

@InjectMocks
AccountService accountService;

@Test
public void remove_staff_updates_roles() {

    Account account = new Account("username", "pass");

    when(accountRepository.findByUsername(any(String.class))).thenReturn(Optional.of(account));

    accountService.updateStaffStatusByUsername("user", false);

    ArgumentCaptor<Account> accountCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Account.class);
    verify(accountRepository).save(accountCaptor.capture());
    assertFalse(accountCaptor.getValue().getRoles().contains(Role.ROLE_STAFF));
}
```